# Problem with linear regression coefficient

Tags: regression, econometrics

I am currently writing my Master's thesis about the internationalization of the Chinese currency "Renminbi" or "Chinese Yuan". I am quiet new to statistical analysis and I am utterly desperate by now.

One authors work relevant to my thesis features a method of analyzing the impact currencies have on other currencies. It has the following formula:

[image: Formula]

Delta means first degree daily variations, the betas are the coefficient (degree of influence on dependent variable) and the currency/SDR is the daily rate to Special Drawing Rights, a kind of artifical currency by the IMF.

In preparing the data I used daily exchange rate data from Datastream. I then took the ln of all daily values and subtracted each of them from the previous day $\ln(X(t))- \ln(X(t-1))$. Alternatively I also tried dividing $X(t)/X(t-1)$ and then took the ln. So I received the daily variations.

Now my problem: if I run the regression now I am getting different results from the authors, which were partly not making sense and always had lower $R^{2}$ values.

Is it possible that my data preperation with the ln and division is spoiled? I an attempt to find my mistake I found out that if I correlate the absolute value (normal and ln) of the currencies for two closely related one's (for example the Euro and Bosnian Dinar) I get a result of 0.9 or more, which makes complete sense.

If I do the same after $X(t)/X(t-1)$ or $\ln(X(t))- \ln(X(t-1))$ I get values far less (sometimes less than $0.1$) what makes absolutely no sense.

Would be really grateful if you can help me out.

Comment: if $X = USD / SDR$  then the ln approach should give the expected result. The only flaw I can see if you have took the inverse exchange rate...

Comment: X would be a number of 60 different currencies, expressed X/SDR. Is that what you mean? The correlation should be pretty much the same, no matter if take absoulut values or relative, right?